# Flutter live notifications

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-notification

I am using Firestore as a database for my flutter app. Some actions on my app lead to change/update in Firestore data.

I am using Flutter native notifications which are generated once a button is clicked. However, the data passed to the notification remains constant despite the data having been updated later in the Firestore.

I would like to implement a feature similar to the one present in sport apps where the live score is updated regularly in the notification.

How can I achieve that in my app? Do I have to use Firestore Cloud Messaging? Citing resources would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve sounds like an ideal case for Firebase Cloud Messaging to be used. I recommend that you take a look at the FlutterFire documentation for Cloud Messaging both [overview](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview/) and [usage](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/), which should give you a good starting point.

Alternatively you can also use a Cloud Function as the host of FCM and only configure your app to receive messages, you can watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NybmemQxdts) for insights on how to create the Cloud Function side.